# Using a cookie to save the state of a toggled division

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

While I've found essentially the same question asked a number of times here and on other sites, I've spent hours and hours trying to get those answers to work on my site to no avail; I'm just plain stumped.  Possibly because I'm fairly new to Javascript, self-taught, and I'm doing this in the first place to try to expand my skills, so I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious to anyone else.

In any event, on my website I have a div for a sidebar, and I'm using jQuery to toggle it and also adjust the parent div to compensate for its absence when it's hidden via a button.  I'd like to be able to use a cookie so that I can refresh without it returning to its default state, but I've never used a cookie before and every tutorial I can find on the subject and every answer I can find to a similar question has resulted in code that just plain doesn't work for reasons I can't figure out.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo12xw79/) of a simplified version of my website.  (Though the toggle script isn't working there for some reason - it works on my website!  I probably missed something when I was simplifying it, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.)

The HTML:

```
<div class="bgcontainer_center">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="toggle">
            <input type="button" value="Toggle Sidebar">
        </div>
        <p>Main Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.bgcontainer_center {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    height: 100%;
}
.bgcontainer_center.clicked {
    max-width: 350px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 125px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 350px;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle("slow");
        $(".bgcontainer_center").toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

Help me?  Bonus points if you can explain it to me so that I actually understand instead of just giving me code that works - I'm trying to learn here!  And feel free to let me know if I've done anything else dumb with my coding.

**Edit:**
Working version, tweaked to function as intended:  https://jsfiddle.net/eo12xw79/3/

Comment: The only issue with your fiddle was the missing jQuery include. Here is the fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/eo12xw79/1/

Comment: You missed to include the jQuery library in your fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store the state.

See the comments inline in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sidebarVisible = localStorage.getItem('sidebar') == 'true'; // Get the value from localstorage
    $('#sidebar').toggle(sidebarVisible); // Toggle sidebar, true: show, false: hide
    $('.bgcontainer_center').toggleClass('clicked', sidebarVisible); // Add class true: add, false: don't add

    $("#toggle").on('click', function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle("slow", function () {
            localStorage.setItem('sidebar', $('#sidebar').is(':visible')); // Save the visibility state in localstorage
        });

        $(".bgcontainer_center").toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/eo12xw79/2/

**LocalStorage**

> The `localStorage` property allows you to access a local Storage object. `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`. The only difference is that, while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the browsing session ends - that is when the browser is closed.

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: +1 - Also, using localStorage here makes more sense than cookies as the toggle state I assume need not be sent to the server.

Comment: Wow, that works almost perfectly - I had to tweak it a little to make it function as intended, but it works well even on my website!  But is it possible to make the sidebar visible by default?  I'd like first-time visitors to see it from the beginning.

Comment: @Avalikia Yes, set the value appropriately. and it should work.